# Unable to change property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I'm trying to change the border of a ComboBox - a seemingly simple task, however nothing is happening.

**EDIT:**

This is my code:

The following appears in an event:

```
cmb.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
cmb.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
```

This is the XAML:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="QueryBuilder.FilterWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" MaxHeight="200" Background="White" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="UserControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Silver"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                        <Border Name="Border" Padding="1" Background="#FFFFFF" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewWithLines}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,5,0,5"/>
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="true"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TreeView Name="tvFilters" Margin="0,10,0,10" Background="White" BorderBrush="White"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

I'm using the default controltemplate for the ComboBox, so I have no idea why it wouldn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't manipulate UI elements in code.

Comment: Did you set the `BorderThickness`?

Comment: Are you on Windows 8? I seem to remember there being some bugs in the way other controls such as the `ToggleButton` were being rendered on Windows 8. I have just tried the solution posted by Dom on my Windows 8 machine and whilst the `BorderThickness` changes the `BorderBrush` does not.

Comment: @Benjamin - I am infact using Windows 8. What would you recommend? I've got it to work for TextBoxes, however not ComboBoxes

Comment: kmatyaszek answer is probably your only viable option at this point I.E. define a new control template.

Comment: Can you provide your current code?

Comment: @DotNET Where does it reference `cmb` in your code?

Comment: @Dom - cmb is just a Combobox that I'm creating dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define new ControlTemplate, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you have all code.

If you want changed border of `ComboBox` you should copy and paste code from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and change only following style:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton 
                        Name="ToggleButton" 
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ClickMode="Press">
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ContentPresenter
                        Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                             Style="{x:Null}" 
                             Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                             Margin="3,3,23,3"
                             Focusable="True" 
                             Background="Transparent"
                             Visibility="Hidden"
                             IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                        <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True" 
                        Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid 
                            Name="DropDown"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                            MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                            MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border 
                                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility"    Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Example of usage:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Height="30" Width="150" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="6" />
```

Result:

[image]

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Height="30" Width="150" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="3" />
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted. Haven't tried your approach yet, but i edited the question

Comment: Ahh ok, So @DotNET you should try it, I tested it and it's working :)

Comment: I tried it quickly, but it changed the look and feel of the ComboBox too much. It looks too weird as it is now :/ Also, still seems to not be working

Comment: @DotNET I prepared for you example solution, you can download it from this link: http://sdrv.ms/ZsH1NG. Let me know if working for you now. Hmmm.. I think that it's only way to changed it, when you try change default style you can't changed `BorderThickness` so you should define new control template.

Comment: My requirements are to change the colour and thickness dynamically though. When trying to do so from code behind in your sample project, nothing happens

Comment: @DotNET check my answer again, if you change border to this: `<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">`, you will able to change properties dynamicly.

Answer (score 1):

What I do when I want to modify styles, i use WPF Inspector (you can find it there: http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/)

And then attach to your ComboBox, and you have access to all properties and styles... you can modify them live and see the result, it's fast....

Maybe your border is null? Or thickness is 0?